# The timestamp to dates problem for PHP >= 5.1

Tags: php

I may say I'm not a PHP programmer. I've been reading at http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php that:

> The valid range of a timestamp is
>   typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901
>   20:45:54 GMT to Tue, 19 Jan 2038
>   03:14:07 GMT. (These are the dates
>   that correspond to the minimum and
>   maximum values for a 32-bit signed
>   integer). However, before PHP 5.1.0
>   this range was limited from 01-01-1970
>   to 19-01-2038 on some systems (e.g.
>   Windows).

I've database full of 1070-based-timestamps. How can I recover them with PHP >= 5.1?

Comment: Can you give us some sample data?

Comment: timestamp 1273866489093 should give a date round these days.

Comment: No, I mean a timestamp that you'd be working with.  One of the ones that you are worried about "recovering."

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that your timestamps will work just fine. The way I read it, before PHP 5.1.0, negative timestamps were not allowed. A timestamp representing a date before 1970 requires a negative 32-bit integer.

In other words, timestamps pre- or post PHP 5.1.0 are all relative to Unix epoch, that is, 1970-01-01.